# Error creating bean with name 'routerFunctionMapping'

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Пытаюсь запустить первое приложение Spring MVC и не могу понять ошибку.

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;


public class SpringWebAppInitializer extends
AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {ApplicationContextConfig.class};
        //return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }


}
```

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;


@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.vokmar" }) 
@EnableWebMvc
public class ApplicationContextConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean(name = "viewResolver")
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new 
        InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
            return viewResolver;
    }


}
```

```
import java.util.Locale;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Model;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;


@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/boqpv", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home() {
        return "home";
    }

}
```

Как решить эту проблему?

```
         Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'routerFunctionMapping' defined in org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.function.support.RouterFunctionMapping]: Factory method 'routerFunctionMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidDefinitionException|#]
              Context initialization failed
            org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'routerFunctionMapping' defined in org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.function.support.RouterFunctionMapping]: Factory method 'routerFunctionMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidDefinitionException
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:645)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:625)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
                at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
                at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
                at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:5043)
                at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:592)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5612)
                at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:540)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:900)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:684)
                at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2044)
                at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1690)
                at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:107)
                at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
                at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
                at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:500)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
                at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:540)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:536)
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:566)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:558)
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1465)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:110)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1847)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1723)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:190)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
                at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
                at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.function.support.RouterFunctionMapping]: Factory method 'routerFunctionMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidDefinitionException
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:640)
                ... 67 more


    ----------
       ...
    <properties>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
            <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            <jakartaee>8.0</jakartaee>
            <spring.version>5.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
            <jstl.version>1.2.1</jstl.version>
            <tld.version>1.1.2</tld.version>
            <servlets.version>3.1.0</servlets.version>
            <jsp.version>2.3.1</jsp.version>

        </properties>
    ....
```

Помогите, кто может...

Comment: `@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)` - не помогло

Answer (score 1):

```
**zolt** - спасибо, ответ был правильный, нужно было подключить необходимые библиотеки.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError - возникает когда класс от которого зависит ваше приложение недоступен при исполнении кода.

com/fasterxml/jackson/**databind/exc**/InvalidDefinitionException - этого не было ни в одном пакете.

Ответ был тут https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin

Нужно было правильно подключить jackson

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-kotlin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

У Вас проблема с зависимостями. Ошибка `nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidDefinitionException` говорит о том, что в момент компиляции класс InvalidDefinitionException был, а в runtime-е его нет. Проверьте список зависимостей на предмет области использования (compile, runtime, etc.). Это `pom.xml` если Вы используете Maven, либо `build.gradle` если Вы используете Gradle.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! 
Я правильно понял речь идёт о <scope>... compile, runtime, etc .....</scope> у меня данного тега нет совсем, по умолчанию, значит compile. Если я не так понял вас, дайте мне знать.